# Delete or parse data in JSON file with JQ or any Linux Tool

Tags: json, linux, jq

I have this JSON file:

```
{
  "vulnerable_configuration_cpe_2_2": [
    "cpe:/o:apple:apple_tv:9.1",
    "cpe:/o:apple:watchos:2.1",
    "cpe:/o:apple:iphone_os:9.2",
    "cpe:/o:apple:mac_os_x:10.11.2"
  ],
  "vulnerable_configuration": [
    {
      "title": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:apple_tv:9.1",
      "id": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:apple_tv:9.1"
    },
    {
      "title": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:watchos:2.1",
      "id": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:watchos:2.1"
    },
    {
      "title": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:iphone_os:9.2",
      "id": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:iphone_os:9.2"
    },
    {
      "title": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:mac_os_x:10.11.2",
      "id": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:mac_os_x:10.11.2"
    }
  ],
  "summary": "The Disk Images component in Apple iOS before 9.2.1, OS X before 10.11.3, and tvOS before 9.1.1 allows local users to gain privileges or cause a denial of service (memory corruption) via unspecified vectors.",
  "references": [
    "https://support.apple.com/HT206168",
    "https://support.apple.com/HT205732",
    "https://support.apple.com/HT205731",
    "https://support.apple.com/HT205729",
    "http://lists.apple.com/archives/security-announce/2016/Mar/msg00001.html",
    "http://lists.apple.com/archives/security-announce/2016/Jan/msg00005.html",
    "http://lists.apple.com/archives/security-announce/2016/Jan/msg00003.html",
    "http://lists.apple.com/archives/security-announce/2016/Jan/msg00002.html"
  ],
  "Modified": "2016-03-29T19:01:26.810-04:00",
  "Published": "2016-02-01T06:59:01.090-05:00",
  "access": {
    "vector": "LOCAL",
    "complexity": "LOW",
    "authentication": "NONE"
  },
  "cvss": 7.2,
  "cvss-time": "2016-03-29T09:43:55.537-04:00",
  "cwe": "CWE-119",
  "id": "CVE-2016-1717",
  "impact": {
    "integrity": "COMPLETE",
    "confidentiality": "COMPLETE",
    "availability": "COMPLETE"
  }
```

I want to delete the following data using JQ or any Linux Tool

- access (including vector, complexity, authentication)
- references: only first or 1 reference
- cvss-time
- vulnerable_configuration_cpe_2_2 (Incluide cpe:/o:apple:apple_tv:9.1,
  etc)

The result, I want it to be this:

```
{
  "vulnerable_configuration": [
    {
      "title": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:apple_tv:9.1",
      "id": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:apple_tv:9.1"
    },
    {
      "title": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:watchos:2.1",
      "id": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:watchos:2.1"
    },
    {
      "title": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:iphone_os:9.2",
      "id": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:iphone_os:9.2"
    },
    {
      "title": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:mac_os_x:10.11.2",
      "id": "cpe:2.3:o:apple:mac_os_x:10.11.2"
    }
  ],
  "summary": "The Disk Images component in Apple iOS before 9.2.1, OS X before 10.11.3, and tvOS before 9.1.1 allows local users to gain privileges or cause a denial of service (memory corruption) via unspecified vectors.",
  "references": [
    "https://support.apple.com/HT206168",
   ],
  "Modified": "2016-03-29T19:01:26.810-04:00",
  "Published": "2016-02-01T06:59:01.090-05:00",
  "cvss": 7.2,
  "cwe": "CWE-119",
  "id": "CVE-2016-1717",
  "impact": {
    "integrity": "COMPLETE",
    "confidentiality": "COMPLETE",
    "availability": "COMPLETE"
  }
```

I try

```
cat file.json | jq ('del(.cvss-time)' and 'access')
```

but no work

What is the command JQ I have to use? Or what tool can I use?

Tanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following filter for jq >= 1.5 meets your requirements:

```
del(.access)
| .references |= [.[0]]
| del(."cvss-time")
| del(.vulnerable_configuration_cpe_2_2)
```

If you are using jq 1.4, use `del(.["cvss-time"])` instead of `del(."cvss-time")`.

Comment: Thanks @peak for the fast Answers... What is the correct command if I want to run everything on a single line?
I tried
`jq '( del(.access)' and 'del(."cvss-time") and del(."vulnerable_configuration_cpe_2_2") and (del(.access) | .references |= [.[0]]))'` but no work

Comment: Just omit the "newlines".  That is: jq 'del(.access) | .references |= [.[0]] | ....'

Comment: Thanks @peak. But..  `cat test.json | jq 'del(."cvss-time")'` no work. I have this error. `del(."cvss-time")
     ^
1 compile error
`

Comment: This error http://i.imgur.com/TYHq5gN.png @peak
It's strange because the command

`cat probar.json | jq 'del(.access) | .references |= [.[0]] | del(.vulnerable_configuration_cpe_2_2)' > result.json` works fine, but I have problems with "CVSS-time"

Comment: Not so strange. You evidently are using an older jq.  See update.